# shining text with custom scrollbar

Tags: css, scrollbar

I am trying to make my own scroll bar. Scroll should appear after hover an element. I prepared some code and all thing is working fine but when I first time hover on element, I have double text but at oher color. When I again hover element, the text disapered. I paste code and screen to get you better point on it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/20GPR.jpg

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: #fff;

    &:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: .5rem;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        display: none;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: .5rem;
        background-color: inherit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. I had `transition` on `all` and after change only on `background`, it works fine